# ASYNC forEach function in JS not occuring in expected order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I seem to be really confused as to how `async` and `await` is supposed to work here. I am trying to get this `forEach` function to occur before the `console.log` and `res.json`.  Unfortunately, even when attaching async and await, it is the last thing to occur.

```
// Setting tags
const tags = ["1", "2", "3"];

app.get("/api/posts", async (req, res) => {    
    try {
        tags.forEach(async function (tag) {
            const response = await fetch(api_url + "?tags=" + tag);
            const response_1 = await response.json();
            console.log(tag);
            await api_json.push(response_1);
        });
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(api_json);
    res.json(api_json);
});
```

And the output:

```
[]
1
2
3
```

I am not sure how else to change the order of which these functions can occur.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `await` makes it look like synchronous code, but the callback you pass to `forEach` is still asynchronous. Your `forEach` is not, so it launches them immediatly, one after the other, not caring about the previous ones fullfilling or not. You may want to replace it with a regular `for` loop and use `await` directly inside of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which is not asynchronous, so you can await each request sequentially.

```
for(const tag of tags){
    const response = await fetch(api_url + "?tags=" + tag);
    const response_1 = await response.json();
    console.log(tag);
    await api_json.push(response_1);
}
```

Comment: @Zernst Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

First, see how `forEach` works.

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
  // this represents our array
  for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
    // We call the callback for each entry
    callback(this[index], index, this);
  }
};
```

As you can see, callback is called but we are not waiting for it to be done before going to the next entry of the array.

That is why this occurs.